# Read a string character by character in ant

Tags: regex, ant

I need to read a String character by character. i.e, If I have a string like CILD, then I have to read it as C and then I and so on.

I tried this with regex and also with properties, but nothing has worked out.

Please let me know a solution for the same.
thanks.

Comment: can you please put what you have tried in your question?

Comment: Try if http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scriptdef.html ant task helps, if you are doing a iteration on all charcaters in a string & doing some specific action on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below snippet in your code to add a _ at end of every character

**propertyregex property="propB" input="${input}" regexp="" replace="_" global="true"**

And then split the property with dleimiter as **"_"**.

**for list="${propB}" delimiter="_" param="split"**

Cheers.

Note : This worked out very well for me.

Comment: Dhinesh, please use greater than and lesser than symbol at the end of each snippet, since i cant add that. :P

Comment: It's also worth noting that the "for" task requires an additional ant-contrib jar. Not a standard ANT task